# Xamarin iOS - Implementing Sign in with Apple

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, apple-sign-in

I am following the implementation instructions here to add Sign in with Apple to an existing Xamarin iOS mobile application:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios13/sign-in

If I simply add the following line to AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching():

```
var appleIdProvider = new ASAuthorizationAppleIdProvider();
```

I receive the following exception:  `System.Exception: Could not create an native instance of the type 'AuthenticationServices.ASAuthorizationAppleIdProvider': the native class hasn't been loaded. It is possible to ignore this condition by setting ObjCRuntime.Class.ThrowOnInitFailure to false.`

I seem to be the only person on the planet that has run into this (and not been able to figure it out themself), as this exact messaging gets zero results on Google.  Am I missing a certain reference?

I'm not sure where to even start looking in order to fix this.  I downloaded the "official" code sample at https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/main/ios13/AddingTheSignInWithAppleFlowToYourApp, and I am unable to find any differences in the project, or in any references.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you compare info.plist and csproj settings?

Comment: Yessir, but I figured it out.  The simulator I was using was iOS 12.5 - ASAuthorizationAppleIdProvider wasn't introduced until iOS 13.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  The simulator I was using was iOS 12.5 - ASAuthorizationAppleIdProvider wasn't introduced until iOS 13.